# Use of “f ” instead of “s” in historic, printed English documents

Tags: orthography, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling, typography

I was at a museum in London yesterday, and one of the items on exhibit is a document from the eighteenth century. It uses the letter *f* a lot where *s* should be used—for example, in *Majefty*.

[image: Her Majeſties moſt Gracious DECLARATION for the incouragement...]

Did the letter *f* once have the same sound as *s* today, or were some of those words actually spoken with an *f* ?

Comment: After a little reading I think this isn't 'Old English', just 'not so modern English'. Can someone more knowledgeable re-title the question?

Comment: It's a "long s" or "medial s" and was a change in typography that also occurred in other languages.  It's not really a question about English.  Also, the wiki page on "long s" probably answers your questions quite satisfactorily.

Comment: @Paul: If this were Old English, you wouldn't be able to read it without a dictionary (see [text samples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English#Text_samples)). In fact, I would say the text in question isn't even [Early Modern English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English). It's just plain Modern English.

Comment: I had wondered about this myself. I didn't know there was a name for this type of s, and that it was common in other languages too.  How fascinating.

Comment: Note also the date "4. June 1702" in cursive below the title.

Comment: Makes it very difficult to read. I also say it in my mind with a lisp. Probably not correct, but I can't help it. Glad the long s got ditched. Interesting history lesson here!

Comment: It may, or may not, bear a relation to German. When I was a student of the German language a letter that looks like an "f" was used as an "s" sound.

Comment: Why were there two forms of 's' in the first place?

Comment: Related question: [What animal is a "weefil"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86774/what-animal-is-a-weefil/86777#86777)

Comment: Should the "f" in the title of this question be changed to a "ſ"

Comment: There were two forms of the small letter *s*.  We see this in the image.  *Long s* used in most cases, but *short s* used at the end of a word.  In some early American documents we see the word *Congreſs* with both of them together.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In the first place, it’s not ***f***, but **long *s***.

It was just a different way of writing *s*. It was always pronounced as an *s* is pronounced; it was never pronounced as an *f*. Its history explains the letter pretty well.  [Long *s*](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Blog/2006/07/long-and-short-of-letter-s.html):

> The long-s originated at a very early date in cursive Roman scripts, and can be seen in both Old Roman Cursive (1st to 3rd centuries AD) and New Roman Cursive (late 3rd century to 7th century).

("The Long and the Short of the Letter S", by Andrew West, *BabelStone Blog*)

It’s no longer used in today’s English. One reason it’s no longer used is [because](http://www.absurdintellectual.com/2011/01/02/a-history-and-usage-of-the-s-long-s/):

> “The death knell,” he writes, “was finally sounded on September 10th 1803 when ... The Times newspaper quietly switched to a modern typeface with no long s or old-fashioned ligatures (this was one of several reforms instituted by John Walter the Second, who became joint proprietor and exclusive manager of The Times at the beginning of 1803).”

This may have been due to the [fact that](http://www.historyofinformation.com/index.php?id=2729):

> Long ‘s’ fell out of use in Roman and italic typography well before the middle of the 19th century; in French the change occurred from about 1780 onwards, in English in the decades before and after 1800, and in the United States around 1820. **This may have been spurred by the fact that long ‘s’ looks somewhat like ‘f ’ (in both its Roman and italic forms), whereas short ‘s’ did not have the disadvantage of looking like another letter, making it easier to read correctly, especially for people with vision problems.**

("The Gradual Disappearance of the Long S in Typography", *Jeremy Norman's HistoryofInformation.com*)

Answer (score 26):

It’s not ***f***  (that is, Unicode codepoint U+0066: `LATIN SMALL LETTER F`), but rather ***ſ***  (meaning [Unicode codepoint U+017F: `LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S`](http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+017f/)).