# The rise of "all of the"

Tags: grammatical-number, typography, language-change

In the following graph, the long *s* accounts for the sudden rise in frequency of *most of the*; if you search for *moft of the,* the lines match up nicely. But what would be behind the sudden increase in the string *all of the* at the beginning of the 20th century?

[image: Frequency of various determinatives in the pattern "DET of the"]
Link [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=many%20of%20the,all%20of%20the,much%20of%20the,any%20of%20the,each%20of%20the,most%20of%20the&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1675&year_end=2000)

The long *s* problem is illustrated here:[image: Google Ngrams for "most of the" and "moft of the"] Link [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=most%20of%20the,moft%20of%20the&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1675&year_end=2000)

Comment: -1 - Please add a link to the ngrams, not just a picture.  Also, "if you search for moft of the, the lines match up nicely" means what?

Comment: I think he means that the fashion for spelling _s_ as _ſ_ in _most_ (_moſt_) would get picked up by Optical Character Scan software as an _f_. But the fashion died out about 1800. That accounts for the first maroon rise; but the red rise a century later is not a spelling matter.

Comment: Would it not be relevant to show 'all the' as well?

Comment: @ Barrie England: No, *all the* wouldn't be relevant for my purposes. I'm looking specifically at the partitive construction. In the phrase *all of the people* the head is *all* where in the phrase *all the people* the head is *people*.

Comment: The OED has 736 citations for ‘all of the’. I suppose you could go through them, noting their dates, and try to establish a pattern of use. Do you have a particular reason for wanting to know?

Comment: Interesting!. The medial s issue is certainly explained in your second chart. Also, Google Ngrams says results outside the time interval 1800-2000 are not reliable (I'll get a link). But your inquiry remains. The only vague rationale that crosses my mind is increased use due to more legal publications, possibly post-Civil War effects too? Is this for the American English corpus?

Comment: I am not sure the sudden increase is statistically significant. Just add "all the" to the mix and see what happens to the graph, for example: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+of+the%2Call+of+the%2Cmuch+of+the%2Cany+of+the%2Ceach+of+the%2Cmost+of+the%2C+all+the&year_start=1675&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @Feral Oink: Civil War effects in the 1900s?

Comment: @JeffSahol: Yes, *all the* is much more frequent and doesn't have the jump. But as I pointed out above, it's a completely different construction. I don't see it as relevant.

Comment: Brett, I only mention it to note that the scale of the jump you noticed, along with all of the variations among the other phrases, is not that significant.

Comment: Yes, *post-Civil War* effects is what I said. My rationale was because of Reconstruction in the South starting in the 1870's and plateauing around World War I. Just a guess. Also, you didn't clarify: Was this for the American English corpus?

Comment: @BrettReynolds Thanks for links; reversed -vote

Comment: @FeralOink: It's the whole corpus. The American corpus shows a similar jump, but the British corpus delays the jump until the 1960s.

Comment: @JeffSahol: significance in corpora is a difficult issue that I admittedly don't understand well. I don't think, however, that simply adding a much more frequent comparator has much to do with it. Perhaps I have misunderstood your meaning though.

Comment: I can't see much difference between [much/most of](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much+of%2Cmost+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [much/most of the](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much+of+the%2Cmost+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in respect of the "sudden" relative rise of *most of* over *much of* between the wars. But *most* was always more common overall - it just hadn't colonised the "idiomatic space" around "of" in the early days.

Comment: Wonder why the all-important *most* **+** *moft* curve is **not** in the graph. That should help a lot in comparison.

Comment: @Kris: because it would drown out everything else, being far more common, and because the question is about *all*, not *most*.

Comment: Oh! right. Though from chart-2 it appears that they would largely cancel out each other. Only I couldn't figure out how to specify (sum of two sub-parameters) for Ngram.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/86775 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/37982 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/96408

Answer (score 2):

The popularity of certain words, phrases and idioms may see dramatic changes at certain points of history.

***[makes sense](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=makes%20sense&year_start=1800&year_end=1950&corpus=5&smoothing=0)***:
(1800-1950 AmE)

[image: ngram for 'makes sense' 1800-1950 AmE]

Wonder what triggered the spike post-1930. Some quote has caught on well and everyone scrambled to use the phrase? Makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes, there's clearly a good deal of serendipity here. But there are also meaningful changes. I'm just curious to know if somebody can propose a plausible reason why *all of the* would behave this way.

Answer (score 1):

The question used *English*, `corpus = 0` as the data set for the analysis.

I ran ngrams queries for your phrase "all of the" for each of the other corpora:  *American English*, *British English*, *English fiction* and *English One Million*. All showed a similar, and quite smoothly increasing trend of rising frequency between approximately 1870 and 1920, with one exception: *British English*, `corpus = 6`

[image: Google Ngram viewer result for British English, <code>corpus = 6</code>]

**[Link to ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all%20of%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3)**

This might be worth pursuing. Without having the benefit of additional context, i.e. the motivation for your inquiry, I can't provide any more specific insights.

Comment: The motivation is mostly curiosity. Why do the other determinatives show reasonably smooth change in the partitive construction while this one has such a jump?

Comment: From a cursory scan, I get the impression earlier instances of *all of the* show a higher percentage of "irrelevant" usages like *are all of the same species*, *nothing at all of the manner*, *deperived them all of the*, etc. In British English I think we just used to say/write *all the* more often, but we now tend to stick *"of"* in there. Perhaps copying Americans.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're stressing a linguistic rather than a social/political explanation, but I read those phrases as reflecting more or less collectivist thought, and the first thing I thought of was the influence of ideas like *nationalism*.

Here's an ngram of *nation, province, town*:

[image]

[Link to ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nation,province,town&year_start=1675&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

However, usage of words like *nation* don't seem to correlate as well for the late 18th century  data shown on your ngrams.

Comment: I don't think this has anything at all to do with a change in the early 1900s.

Comment: Keith, that was a clever idea, about the rise of nationalism (or populism?) in the 40+ year interval from the 1870's through 1920 or so. I would have tried checking that, if I'd thought of it! The results you got don't seem to support the idea, unfortunately. At least, not for the terms you ran. But I wonder if others would...?

Comment: In the graph, I'm (non-rigorously!) pointing at that brief rise in use of the term "nation" in the early 1900s, and contrasting that with the steadily declining use of what I think of as "local" words like "province" and "town". Whether "nation" usage reflects a rise in the popularity of a concept of nationalism or not I don't know, but I think the rebirth and reformulation of the concept at that time (early 1900s) is pretty well established historically. But maybe other better words could be found to reflect that more, as you say!