# What animal is a “weefil”?

Tags: typography, early-modern-english, image-identification

What animal is depicted in this image labelled “weefil”?

[image: Old woodcut labelled “Weeſil”]

Comment: Can you share the image source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of “f ” instead of “s” in historic, printed English documents](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37982/use-of-f-instead-of-s-in-historic-printed-english-documents)

Comment: @RegDwighт: I dunno. Certainly, tchrist's much-evolved answer could now almost equally apply to that question, but I think that's because he has buried the actual 'weasel' part of the answer in lots of other information about typefaces.

Comment: That's not a weefil—it's a ftoat.

Comment: It's a weeſil ... and the ſpelling of it is perfectly fine as is.

Answer (score 117):

## *f*  vs  *ſ*

---

That’s merely [a “long *s*”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s), not an *f*.

[image: wikipedia long s example]

Therefore, it is not a ***weefil*** but rather a ***weeſil*** — meaning of course, a ***weasel***.

We can rule out [*weevil*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weevil) be­cause it 
has the look not of a bug but of a [*muste­line*
crit­ter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names).

Here are some ex­am­ples in var­i­ous faces — name­ly, in **ro­man, ital­ic,
script, un­cial,** and **black­let­ter** faces — of just how con­fus­ing this
can some­times be to the un­ini­ti­at­ed:

[image: font examples]

Although the “long s” is per­haps es­pe­cial­ly known for its use in
black­let­ter (al­so known as *Frak­tur*) faces, and black­let­ter forms 
are of­ten as­so­ci­at­ed with Ger­many, in fact the long s orig­i­nat­ed
in Ro­man times, long be­fore Gut­en­berg in­vent­ed mov­able type. It was
reg­u­lar­ly used in hand­writ­ing for many, many cen­turies, and sur­vived 
in­to our mod­ern ro­man and ital­ic faces as shown above.

The let­ter that re­mains part of Ger­man but is no longer used in English 
is the “sharp s”, which orig­i­nat­ed as a lig­a­ture con­nect­ing a “long 
s” with a “round s”: *ſ* + *s* = *β*, in a man­ner of speak­ing. Some of
the spe­ci­mi­na shown above make this es­pe­cial­ly ob­vi­ous if you look
close­ly at the dif­fer­ence on the end of *sin­ful­ness* and 
*self­ish­ness* as shown in the sec­ond ver­sus the third col­umn.

See al­so the ques­tion [Dur­ing what pe­ri­od of his­to­ry did English use 
“ß”, the “sharp s” lig­a­ture?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96408/2085)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musteline would be a better line. Nice answer :)

Comment: all of that because it has roots in the long S of German origin?

Comment: @Chris No, the long *s* is actually not of German origin, but Roman, and was used in many languages both in handwriting and later in print. Furthermore, its use was not limited to blackletter faces (or hands) alone. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s), [here](http://www.colonialsense.com/Society-Lifestyle/Signs_of_the_Times/Long_S.php), and if you’d like, perhaps also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter).

Answer (score 38):

That's not an F, it's an S. You can tell because the bar doesn't cross the stem. Once you figure that out, it's pretty easy to deduce that *weesil* is an old spelling of *weasel*. Plus, the picture is obviously of something weasel-oid.

Here's a pretty good overview of the history of the long S in printing, including the rules (or rather, lack thereof) for using long vs. short S: 
[“The Long S
in *Colonial Sense*”](http://www.colonialsense.com/Society-Lifestyle/Signs_of_the_Times/Long_S.php).

Answer (score 4):

Others have already rightfully pointed out that this is a ***weasel***. As a member of the [Mustelidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustelidae) family, it is related to the ***sea otter***.

In Maine, these were known as [***lobsters***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Areas_of_My_Expertise#The_Furry_Lobster), which were subsequently driven to extinction by [*crustaceans*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_lobster) now commonly known as *lobsters*. The last of these *old* lobsters died in 1980.

[image: a furry old lobster]

<sub>Pictured: A "furry old lobster"</sub>

Full Disclaimer: The second paragraph of this answer is complete fiction. Any factual [resemblance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwa_hirsuta) is purely coincidental. Both the *old* "furry old lobster" and modern-day "lobster" are alive and well.

Comment: "Hodgman's story is, of course, entirely fictional"

Comment: Of course it's fictional, there's still plenty of old lobsters in Maine today.

Comment: I think you maybe ought to emphasize that calling them "furry lobsters" is a joke, and that they aren't really extinct.

Comment: @KitFox Fictional claims do not belong in the answer at all.