# During what period of history did English use “ß”, the “sharp s” ligature?

Tags: typography, early-modern-english, german, ligature

The *ß* glyph is a lowercase letter that represents a ligature between a long *s* (*ſ*) and a round *s*, and is still used today in (some versions of) German.  Its uppercase equivalent is two characters instead of one: *SS*.

It was apparently also once used in just the same way English, but I cannot find just exactly when or where.  Was it used in manuscripts only, or in printed books too?  During what time period would this have run?  If in print, was it done only in blackletter faces in English, or was it also done in the less German-looking ones?

---

Somewhat related is the question [What animal is a “weefil”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/86774/2085).

Comment: What sort of evidence do you have that it was once also used in English? (presumably not actual text)

Comment: @Mitch If you look at the letter reproduced below, it was clearly used there.

Comment: When you wrote the original question, had you seen for yoirself such a thing or had you only heard about it?

Comment: @Mitch I had seen it before, yes. It was not just some hypothetical.

Comment: If you do a [full-text search in the OED](http://www.oed.com/search?f_0=Full+Text&isWritersAndEditors=true&pageSize=20&q_0=%C3%9F&scope=ENTRY&searchUri=All&type=dictionarysearch) you get two results of it used as a single character. One is probably a 2007 typo for beta, but I'm not sure about the other from 1726: "Tartar prepared with Nitre ℥i. Orange Pills ℥ß. Infuse them in a Pint of Parsly-Water."

Comment: @tchrist this is wrong, [ß is the ligature of a long ſ and a z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ß) (the German name gives it away, too: Eszett) ... meanwhile a capitalized version of ß also exists, but doubling the S is arguably more common. It would make sense that it has been used like this in English, because in typographers would use the same rules to set a ligature of ſ and z. As they do nowadays for fi and other letter combinations.

Comment: Researching this, I think your question makes an assumption that is wrong. And that assumption is that ß is identical to a ſs ligature, which it's not. They look similar, but so does the Greek letter β. Somehow I get the feeling that this is somewhat similar to how people these days use [Y](https://unicode-table.com/en/0059/) when attempting to style something as old, just because the written from of þ somewhat resembles/resembled the written form of y. But I'd love to get authoritative references to sources contradicting me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[If this source is to be believed](http://opentype.info/blog/2012/11/20/whats-a-ligature/), the German *Eszett* is an intentional, early 20th century borrowing into Antiqua from Fraktur of a ligature of *ſ* and *z* — whether or not, in any given font, the Eszett resembles the *ſ-s* ligature is apparently purely a matter of typographical taste.

As for the *ſ-s* ligature itself, it would have been in use only as long as long *s* was in use, which seems to have been [until the early 19th century](http://typefoundry.blogspot.com/2008/01/long-s.html).

EDIT: If Wikipedia’s to be believed, what I wrote above is wrong, and Andrew Leach should be correct that the *ſ-s* ligature had fallen completely from favour in English, at least by the 18th century. However, that ligature *does* seem to have seen use in English in the 16th and 17th centuries, if only in the italic not roman. See [here, under “Rules for Long S in Early Printed Books”](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Blog/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html) for examples, where “the True Copie of a Letter from the Qveenes Maiestie, London 1586” featured below is discussed.  Note the *ſ-s* ligatures here:

---

[image: The True Copie of a Letter from the Qveenes Maiestie, London 1586]

Comment: Another cool thing here is "bleſ-ſing" split across two lines at the bottom using double long S. This proves that it really was a ligature in the other words.

Answer (score 8):

The *ß* ligature was used as part of the apothecaries' system of weights and measures used throughout Europe. Often Latin was used as the lingua franca, but it was also used in English medical recipes.

Here's an example from Sir John Floyer's *A Treatise Of The Asthma* (1726):

> Tartar prepared with Nitre ℥i. Orange Pills ℥ß. Infuse them in a Pint of Parsly-Water.

The funny z-squiggle (℥) is the apothecaries' ounce sign (Unicode hexadecimal: 0x2125). The *i* is the Roman numeral for one, and *ß* is from *ss* meaning *semis*, or a half. This recipe requires tartar prepared with one ounce of nitre and half an ounce of orange peels.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothecaries%27_system#Medical_recipes):

> There was a technical reason why *3 ʒ* was written *ʒiij*, and *1⁄2 ʒ* as *ʒß* or *ʒss*: The letters "ss" are an abbreviation for the Latin "semis" meaning "half," while the [Sharp S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_S) ("ß") is an abbreviation for "ss." In Apothecaries' Latin, numbers were generally written, in Roman numerals, immediately following the symbol. Since only the units of the apothecaries' system were used in this way, this made it clear that the civil weight system was not meant.

Comment: http://shapecatcher.com helped me identify ℥ as the apothecaries' ounce sign.

Comment: I wonder whether this is somehow related to ℔ ...

Comment: @Hugo - Gold star for that! Many times in the past I could have made good use of this software. Must remember shapecatcher.

Answer (score 8):

[image: 1870 U.S. census, population schedules. NARA microfilm publication M593, 1,761 rolls. Washington, D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, n.d.Minnesota census schedules for 1870. NARA microfilm publication T132, 13 rolls. Washington, D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, n.d.]Longhand "sharp s" was still utilized during the late 19th century in the American Midwest. As you can see from the attached 1870 US Federal Census, the census enumerator on lines 38 and 39 scribed "Melissa" and "Clarissa" as Malißa (sic) and Clarißa.

Comment: Wow! Very impressive find!

Comment: These do not look like sharp S but more like long S. This is especially clear in “Harneſs Maker”. And interesting the inconsistencies. “Maliſsa” and “Clariſsa”, and “Harneſs Maker” – but “Missouri”. Also no long S in “Millersburg”, “Reason”, “Rosetta”, “Teamster”, or “English Township”.

Comment: @MetaEd I don't know for English, but going by the German rules for the long ſ Millersburg would be perfectly right, because it's a compound word from Millers (s is at the end) and burg. Reason however should be Reaſon and I also think Rosetta should use a ſ. Teamster seems right again, though, because of the t that follows (special rule as far as I'm aware). I wonder what the rules for the long ſ in English are/were.

Answer (score 6):

The *ß* **ligature** was **never** used in English typography, even when the long s was customary, for example when it was followed by a short s at the end of a word like *Congress* (see the US Bill of Rights).

[image: Long S in US Bill of Rights]

The long s–short s combination was **always** set as two separate characters, *ſs*, and although some Continental type founts combined them into a single glyph, it wasn't used in English printing.

[Wikipedia has rather a nice illustration showing](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%C3%9F&oldid=959346649#Graphical_variants) how ſs became a ligature and adopted its current customary shape. Shape 3 is still often seen (for example on German street signs), and shape 2 is still available in some typefaces.

[image: Development of SZ ligature]

Comment: 1. It is not absolutely true that the long _s_--short _s_ ligature was never used in English---16th and 17th century examples of this, albeit in italics, can be found here, under "Rules for Long S in Early Printed Books": http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Blog/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html

2. 3. and 4. are _not_ long _s_--short _s_ ligatures, but rather Antiqua adaptations of a long _s_--z ligature in Fraktur, at least if the account I linked to is to be believed.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić That blog post doesn't illustrate an ſs ligature -- plenty of others, but not ſs, which rather proves my point. The rules for German spelling and the modification/reuse of ſs for ſz are not relevant (although I thought that the development of ſs as an Antiqua ligature was interesting).

Comment: Take a look at the excerpts from "The True Copie of a Letter from the Qveenes Maiestie" (1586) and "Micrographia" (1665): the former definitely has _witneße_ and _goodneße_ and _thankfulneße_ and _bleßings_, whilst the latter definitely has _Addreß_. To be fair, the use of _ß_ does seem to be rather sporadic. As for examples 3. and 4., those are very specifically forms of the German Eszett, and are thus ligatures of _ſ_ and _s_ only in so far as the German Eszett is.

Comment: I can't find the ligature in *Micrographia*. As for the *Letter*, I'd like to know where and when that edition was printed.

Comment: The _Letter_ is a pamphlet printed in London in 1586, if the website is to be believed. As for Micrographia, look at the very first sentence: "AFter my _Addreß_ to our _Great Founder_..."

Comment: Links would be useful!

Comment: The same article as before, http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Blog/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html, under "Rules for Long S in Early Printed Books."

Comment: I walked past the site of Shakespeare's Globe theatre this weekend (here: http://goo.gl/maps/kIKcn). I noticed one of the maps reproduced on the information boards has a building labelled "Eßex House". Next time I'm nearby I'll check the date.

Comment: It looks like @BranimirĆaćić is right, that it really was used in English at some point, and for some period.

Comment: I’m afraid, Andrew, that the evidence does seem to show that it did get used, at least during some parts of the 16th century, although certainly not everywhere nor necessarily all that consistently.  The “rules for long s” referenced above really are quite interesting.

Comment: @tchrist nope, I think you're wrong and you're conflating things here. The image - taken from Wikipedia (I edited in a link and hope it gets approved) - shows two different things in Roman typefaces: ſs as separate letters, ſs as a ligature (that's - I believe - the _actual_ one you were after, not ß!) and the sz-ligature from the Fraktur typeface "translated" into Roman typeface to become ſʒ and the modern form ß derived from that ſʒ ligature. To confuse things further the article conflates the ss and ß spelling for Straße/Strasse which have been used at different times.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a bit late to this, but the ß was used on the letterhead of the Clarendon Press [Preß] at Oxford in 1963.  I can't say I've ever seen another example in 20th-century English.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced. Sure, this looks like an ß. But by all accounts of non-German speakers so does the Greek β. I think this is indeed a stylized ligature of ſ and s used for typographical purposes, but unrelated to ß. As far as I know the ß came about as a ligature of ſ and ʒ (the former being a long s and the latter being a z closer to its form in Fraktur). But obviously if you'd want to create a ligature between long ſ and s the above would be the outcome, given the Roman typefaces. I just wonder if there's an actual relation between what seems to be ſ-s and ſ-ʒ.

Comment: Even the Germans didn't use the modern form of the eszett before 1903. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Representation).

Comment: @PeterShor which isn't surprising, because most of the books of the era and earlier are typeset in Fraktur. And in Fraktur there was simply no need for the modern form, which came about when the ſʒ-ligature was "ported" to Antiqua (Roman typefaces). Personally I have not seen a single German book that wasn't set in Fraktur from around 1930 and before (and I own quite a few). But they probably exist.

Answer (score 4):

[image]Have a look at the UK channel 5 tv programme on ‘The Great Plague’ broadcast today 18 Nov 2020.  Looked like an example from 1665 to me.  But I’m no linguist....

Apologies.  Here's the screenshot that I should have included.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. But I'm sorry, this [isn't an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Answers need to be complete in themselves: you need to include a screenshot at least.