# Name of the archaic "F" character used for an "S"

Tags: orthography, typography

Into the 19<sup>th</sup> century, accepted orthography often used a letter character that resembles an F (but is not in fact identical to an F) when today we would invariably use an S.

- What is this character called?
- What were the orthographic rules of its usage?
- Was it inherited from the German language?

Comment: It's an S. OK, OK, if you want to be more specific, it's a "long S". There were no rules of usage, and don't listen to anyone who tries to tell you otherwise. The glyph predates the German language.

Comment: Oh, and see [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86774/what-animal-is-a-weefil) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37982/use-of-f-instead-of-s-in-historic-printed-english-documents?rq=1).